# What should be added to brownies when reducing cocoa powder and vanilla extract?

Tags: baking, flavor, chocolate, brownies, tasting

I have a brownie recipe. The first time I tried them they turned out great but had a strong taste of chocolate and vanilla extract. I halved the cocoa powder and vanilla essence required to reduce the flavour as I prefer mild chocolatey taste but the brownies were no longer fudgy. Shall I add some flour when removing cocoa powder and vanilla extract. Here's the recipe:

Ingredients

- 1 cup butter (melted and cooled)
- 2 tablespoons vegetable oil
- 1 cup plus 2 tablespoons brown sugar
- 1 cup plus 2 tablespoons white sugar
- 4 large eggs
- 4 teaspoons vanilla extract
- 1 cup all purpose flour
- 1 cup unsweetened cocoa powder
- 1 teaspoon salt
- 1 1/2 cups chopped chocolate

Method:

1. In a large bowl combine melted butter, oil, and both sugars.
2. Add the eggs, vanilla and salt then whisk for about one minute.
3. Over the same bowl sift in the flour and cocoa powder. Gently fold the dry ingredients into the wet ingredients. Fold the chocolate chunks.
4. Bake for 35-40 minutes at 170'C

Comment: If you don't want them to taste too strongly of chocolate, it seems like the easiest first step is to take out the chocolate chunks. Did you try that?

Comment: If you want mild chocolate flavor, just buy a boxed brownie mix. Usually the goal of a from scratch recipe is to obtain intense chocolate flavor that's not available in (the cheaper) boxes mixes.

Comment: 4 teaspoons of vanilla! That's far too much, 1 tsp is plenty for those quantities.

Comment: You can swap the chocolate chunks for milk chocolate (if you're not doing that already), and swap the cocoa powder for hot cocoa mix and reduce the sugar (since cocoa mix already has sugar in it)

Comment: When you say no longer fudgy what do you mean? What consistency did you get?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the ratios appear off from my experience. For my brownie recipe (ratio for 9x9 dish), I use 1/4 cup of cocoa powder with 3/4 cup of flour, 1 cup of sugar, 2 eggs, 1/2 cup of butter, 1 teaspoon vanilla extract, and 1-1.5 cups of chocolate chips. You can do this with or without the cocoa chips, and it should be less or mildly chocolatey without being overbearing. Applying this ratio to your recipe...

1. 1.5 cups of flour
2. 1/2 cup of cocoa powder

I'm not sure the vegetable oil is needed with having 1 cup of butter. I'd agree with some of the comments and would reduce this to 2 teaspoons of vanilla extract; otherwise, this looks like a great brownie recipe by adding brown sugar!

Comment: Vegetable oil in baked goods makes them moister and keeps them moist after cooling. Butter contributes to general richness and helps them rise better

Comment: Thanks for that explanation -- I never knew, and this makes total sense.